# How to fill XML with XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I would like to know if is it possible to fill a XML file using XSL with Java. I mean, I have an empty XML (empty tags are already in it) and I want to transform it using XSL, is it possible to put data and save this XML?

This is an example what i want:

Empty XML:

```
<entidad></entidad>
<gestor></gestor>
```

The XSL:

```
<h4>
  <xsl:value-of select="entidad" />
</h4>
<div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left;">Gestor:</div>
    <div class="col-md-5">                            
        <xsl:value-of select="gestor" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The final XML:

```
<entidad>Demo demo</entidad>    
<gestor>Demo demo</gestor>
```

I have already searched about DOM and XSL but I can't find anything.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Where should this "Demo demo" String come from? And what is the HTML doing in the XSL?

Comment: The String "Demo demo" comes from the HTML generated by XSL.
I want to insert "demo demo" in the HTML generated by the XSL and save it in the XML file.

Comment: So if your input is empty XML and your output is filled XML, why do you have HTML inside the XSL? What is it for?

Comment: I have to take the XML file, transform it into a HTML so the client fill it with some data and re-transform the HMTL to a XML in order to save the client's input.
I have already done the first transformation but I don't know if the second one is even possible.

Comment: Getting client's input from HTML form is a separate issue (and I don't think it has to do anything with Java). Once you have the data, you can use it to transform the original XML.

Comment: Take a look at XForms. I think you're re-inventing the wheel, and getting it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, ill try with XForms